# Accessing global instance of a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on figuring out C++ still. What I've been trying to do is make global instances of certain classes (the class controlling input stored in a global variable, the class controlling graphics stored in a global variable, the class controlling the overall game system stored in a variable, etc.) It's been working fine so far. But now I need to give an instance of the input controller data from the system controller.

In my game.h file (the one that runs the main loop and a few other things), I have defined the system as such

"global gameSystem"

in game.cpp I can access a variable in there named "keyCodes"

In my input.cpp file, I've included game.h and global.h (it didn't work with just game.h, so thought I'd try global.h too), and I can see the instance of gameSystem, but I cannot access it's keyCodes variable.

Any idea how to fix this? This sort of thing worked for me when I programmed in AS3 and Ruby. I like how modular it keeps things. So I'd really like to do it the same way in this x.x

Comment: You should give us some sample code; it sounds like your code isn't doing what you think it's doing. For example, a statement `global gameSystem` would instantiate an instance of class `global` named `gameSystem`.

Comment: Global variables are usually a terrible idea.  You'd be better off creating a "context" class that stores all of the objects you need for one instance of the game and pass around a reference to it.  Many lifetime issues (like the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)) go away entirely (or are more easily managed) by having your "globals" live in one object, allocated from your `main()`.

Comment: Use the singleton pattern. This will give you alot more controll and make things transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to guess exactly what you are doing. From my perspective I understand that you have a global variable in one file and want to access it in another. If that is the case you have to do the following (I'll make an example with an `int` but any other type is the same.

Create a `File1.h` header file where you tell the world that a global `int` variable, named `MyGlobalInt` exists with the following line:

```
// This is File1.h
extern int MyGlobalInt;
```

This just announces that the variable exists. It **does not** declare the variable. To declare the variable you do so in a `File1.cpp`:

```
// This is File1.cpp
#include "File1.h"
int MyGlobalInt;
```

File1.cpp declares the variable. Now it can be used in any file that includes `File1.h`. For instance in `File2.cpp`:

```
// This is File2.cpp
#include "File1.h"
void ChangeGlobalInt(int newValue)
{
  MyGlobalInt = newValue;
}
```

In you case, you should put

```
extern Whatever_type_you_are_using keyCodes;
```

in file `game.h`. File `game.cpp` should `#include "game.h"` and declare effectively `keyCodes`:

```
#include "game.h"
Whatever_type_you_are_using keyCodes;
```

Now, every file that includes "game.h" will be able to use `keyCodes`.

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing. Sorry for how unclear my question was. x.x I had all the variables setup properly, but I forgot to access the instance of game that they were all stored in. So in main, I declared my game class outside of main, and now I can access it (And it's associated variables) from anywhere in the program.